# Proof $\sum_{n\ge1} \frac{n!}{x(x+1)\cdot\dots\cdot(x+n-1)}$ ($x>0$) convergence/divergence.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

First I noticed that the series can be rewritten to $\sum_{n\ge1}\frac1{\binom{x}{n}}$. Applying root test: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{\binom{x}{n+1}}{\binom{x}{n}}\right| = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{\binom{x}{n} \cdot \frac{x-n}{n-1}}{\binom{x}{n}}\right| = 1 $. This test is inconclusive. I'm trying hard to find a series to compare to the given one, but I can't seem to find one. Any hints?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It is easy enough to show for integers, but we can rewrite in terms of Gamma functions instead so that we can use related asymptotics
$$
\frac{1}{\binom{x}{n}}=\frac{n!}{x(x+1)\dotsb(x+n-1)}
= \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(x+n)\,/\,\Gamma(x)}
= \frac{\Gamma(x)}{n^{x-1}} \frac{\Gamma(n)\cdot n^x}{\Gamma(n+x)}
$$

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function):

> Another useful limit for asymptotic approximations is:
>   $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\Gamma(n+\alpha)}{\Gamma(n)n^{\alpha}},\quad \alpha\in\mathbb{C}$$

hence
$$ \frac{1}{\binom{x}{n}} / \frac{1}{n^{x-1}} \to \Gamma(x) > 0,\quad \text{for $x > 0$}$$

The limit comparison test then says that the series converges or diverges with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{x-1}}$, a "$p$-series", that converges if and only if $x>2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u_n$ be the $n$-th term in the series. Then $R_n=\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\frac{n+1}{x+n}$.

So we see that the series diverges if $x \leq 1$ because the sequence is nonzero and nondecreasing.

Now we assume $x=1+y, y > 0$.

Then $R_n=1-\frac{y}{n}\frac{1}{1+x/n}= 1-\frac{y}{n} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$.

Thus $\ln(u_{n+1})-\ln(u_n)=\ln(R_n)=-yn^{-1}+O(n^{-2})$.

As a consequence, $\ln(u_n)$ goes to $-\infty$ and is equal to $-y\ln(n)+z+o(1)$ for some constant $z$.

Thus $u_n \sim e^zn^{-y}$, hence the series converges iff $y > 1$ ie $x >2$.